# Will it be safe to give 14.7 VDC to this network switch rated for 12VDC?

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc, dc-dc-converter, lifepo4

I have a number of video devices and a 1GbE network switch which are being powered by a 12VDC LiFePo4 battery via a DC power distribution module, using powerpole connectors.

All of the devices are rated to operate at approx 12-18 VDC, but the network switch (Netgear GS105) is only rated for exclusively 12 VDC. Its max power consumption is 2.7W (0.225 A) and its manufacturer wall adapter supplies 12 VDC / 0.5A.

I am concerned if I connect the switch to my distro, that the battery's range from 14.7V at 100% charge down to 12V and lower, will be bad for the switch & deliver too high or too low a voltage for what it is rated.

**Will it be safe to give 14.7 VDC to this network switch?**

Or do I need to regulate the 12VDC using a DC-DC converter or voltage regulator?

Comment: The device says it needs 12 V. So you need to supply it with 12 V. If you supply more than 12 V you risk the device getting damaged. It could be that the device is well designed and can actually handle more. But we don't know as we didn't design it. My point: no one here will say "it's OK" because if someone did and the device would get damaged, who is to blame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what's on the receiving end of the input power for the GS105 you won't be able to tell from the publicly available documentation it seems.  Because the GS105 is around $25-30 USD you can always try plugging in just the 14.7V supply and seeing if you let the magic smoke out.  My suspicion is that even if you don't immediately fry the GS105 at the power input side you may have some unintended long term side effects.

Depending on your intended end application of the system you will likely want to get an actual 12V supply that can provide adequate power to the GS105.  It doesn't seem likely you'd end up damaging anything connected to the GS105 if it does decide to off itself, but that assumption is also based on the amount of risk you want to take with things connected to the GS105 as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is fair. I have photographed the circuit inside the GS105 to try and identify if it has any input voltage regulation but I can't see any obvious model numbers or chips that I can identify online.

Since I do need the GS105 to be battery powered, I'm going to look at ways to regulate the supply just for it. I was hoping to design an inline power cable similar to [this cable](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1448823-REG/lanparte_dtap_12v_d_tap_to_5010_12v.html/overview), but I may also end up buying one and re-terminating one end to powerpole.